# Code is run between two lines in PHP and Xdebug can't debug it

Tags: php, phpstorm, xdebug

I can't wrap my head around this, and I can't really debug it any further: [image]

So I have a breakpoint in index.php at line 2, and when I step over the lines of code the variable $GLOBALS["retina_display"] evaluates to "null", but when I step between line 4 and line 5 it is set to "foobar". It's foobar because I had to look at all the places in my project where I manipulate this variable and change it to see what triggered it, and it's in graphics.php. What really boggles my mind is that this is run **between** the fourth and fifth line. The breakpoint I have in graphics.php does not trigger at all but is obviously executed.

Why is the graphics.php breakpoint not triggered? Why is any code at all run between line 4 and 5? I'm pulling my hair and I can't understand what is happening??

Comment: `$page->view` may be [calling an  `__set`  "overloading" function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php). If so, Xdebug should offer to "step into" that, I think.

Comment: By the way, you should [avoid uploading images of code/data/errors](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) - text is better pasted as text, with an explanation of where the breakpoints were placed.

Comment: @IMSoP I have tried to step into and force step into it but nothing. And also, that should still trigger the graphics.php breakpoint, right?

Comment: Having debug watches sometimes messes up code execution. Try removing all of them and checking if it behaves differently

Comment: FWIW, I have received a bug report wrt to setting `$GLOBALS` recently (https://bugs.xdebug.org/view.php?id=2130) — can you confirm your PHP and xdebug versions please?